# Build query that brings only sessions that have only errors?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with sessions events names. Each session can have 3 different types of events.

There are sessions that have only error type event and I need to identify them by getting a list those session.

I tried the following code:

```
SELECT
    test.SessionId, SS.RequestId 
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         SSE.SessionId,
         SSE.type,
         COUNT(SSE.SessionId) OVER (ORDER BY SSE.SessionId, SSE.type) AS total_XSESIONID_TYPE,
         COUNT(SSE.SessionId) OVER (ORDER BY SSE.SessionId) AS total_XSESIONID
     FROM 
         [CMstg].SessionEvents SSE 
     -- WHERE SSE.SessionId IN ('fa3ed523-60f9-4af0-a85f-1dec9e9d2cdb' )
   ) AS test
WHERE
    test.total_XSESIONID_TYPE = test.total_XSESIONID
    AND test.type = 'Errors'
    -- AND test.SessionId IN ('fa3ed523-60f9-4af0-a85f-1dec9e9d2cdb' )
```

1. Each session can have more than one type, and I need to count only the sessions that have only type 'errors'. I don't want to include sessions that have additional types of events in the count
2. While I'm running the first query I'm getting a count of 3 error event per session, but while running the all procedure the number is multiplied to 90?

Sample table :

| sessionID | type |
| --- | --- |
| fa3ed523-60f9-4af0-a85f-1dec9e9d2cdb | Errors |
| fa3ed523-60f9-4af0-a85f-1dec9e9d2cdb | Errors |
| fa3ed523-60f9-4af0-a85f-1dec9e9d2cdb | Errors |
| 00c896a0-dccc-41bf-8dff-a5cd6856bb76 | NonError |
| 00c896a0-dccc-41bf-8dff-a5cd6856bb76 | Errors |
| 00c896a0-dccc-41bf-8dff-a5cd6856bb76 | Errors |
| 00c896a0-dccc-41bf-8dff-a5cd6856bb76 | Errors |

In this case I should get

```
sessionid = fa3ed523-60f9-4af0-a85f-1dec9e9d2cdb
```

Please advice - hope this is clearer now, thanks!

Comment: it is not homework....it is part of some data cleansing that i must perform before implementing analytics

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time but I think something like this should get you the desired results:

```sql
SELECT securemeSessionId
FROM <TableName> -- replace with actual table name
GROUP BY securemeSessionId
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'errors' THEN 1 END)
```

And a pro tip: When asking [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) questions, it's best  to follow [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM NameOfDataBase 
WHERE type!= 'errors'
```

Is it what you wanted to do?